# Is it safe to copy a class into uninitialized memory?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-assignment

I have to use `malloc` to allocate memory. I have a custom class that needs a custom `operator=`. Let's say it is `A`:

```
class A {
public:
  int n;
  A(int n) : n(n) {}
  A& operator=(const A& other) {
   n = other.n;
   return *this;
  }
};
```

I allocate memory with `malloc`:

```
int main() {
   A* a = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));
   A b(1);

   //Is it safe to do this as long as I copy everything in operator=?
   *a = b;

   //Clean up
   a->~A();
   free(a);
   return 0;
}
```

I know I can also use placement new:

```
a = new (a) A(b);
```

Is it safe to copy a custom class to uninitialized memory?

 
Thanks

Comment: What makes you think you have to use `malloc` ...

Comment: I was working on a embedded system where I thought new wasn't implemented. I implemented a vector class with malloc and I was greeted by some obscure runtime errors, which disappeared when I changed it to new. Now I'm just curious, because I haven't found this anywhere.

Comment: The problem isn't malloc, the problem is there is no object `A` at that spot unless you create it properly. Assignment relies on it being created already. The more complex your code becomes, the more likely this will pop up and bite you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placement new is correct

using `A& operator=(const A& other)` with a non constructed "`this`" is incorrect (imagine if you have a non trivial type as `std::string` inside `A` the affectation should destroy a non initialized string before affecting the new value).

Once you have do placement new, you can use assignment.

```
auto p = new (a) A;
*p = b; // ok
```

Comment: Do you have any links where I can investigate more? Thanks

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime, *"Access outside of lifetime"*

Comment: Is that still true for POD types? I think I can assign types like int, char, etc, but what about POD classes?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not "safe" to do this. The assignment operator copies its argument into **an existing object**. A **constructor** turns raw memory into an object. When you're dealing with raw memory you don't have an object, so assigning to it doesn't make any sense. You **must** use a constructor. So, placement new is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, copy assignment (or any member function) on a non-existing object is not OK.

Besides placement new, you could instead call `std::uninitialized_copy_n` or `std::uninitialized_copy`(which will do the placement construction internally. This is handy when you need to copy-construct multiple objects into uninitialized memory. Example for your single object:

```
std::uninitialized_copy_n(&b, 1, a);
```

Comment: The real question then becomes how would you destruct the objects, e.g. std::uninitialized_delete_n...

Comment: Actually I suppose C++ 17 did this with std::destroy_n otherwise maybe std::for_each with std::destroy_at (nope C++ 20) - so ::delete(ptr) would do it.

Comment: @GregoryMorse the storage is no longer uninitialized after you have constructed the objects, so `std::uninitialized_delete_n` wouldn't make sense. The correct solution is to simply call the destructor directly which is what Pedro does in their example. Use any loop to repeat for multiple objects. destroy_n and _at see nice shorthands to do this if you can use C++17. ::delete(ptr) is wrong. It releases the memory and does not destroy the objects.

Comment: Agreed the destructor is the correct way.  The new C++17 and C++20 functions do just that.